# ¿Cómo se implementa el ruteo en php siguiendo un modelo MVC?

Tags: php, mvc

Puede que la pregunta sea algo imprecisa. Estoy introduciéndome al mundo del backend y me surgió la necesidad de implementar un sistema de ruteo en un proyecto.

Pretendo evitar el uso de rutas como: `require_once("../../carpeta_del_recurso/recurso.php")` ya que si cambia la ubicación de los archivos, volvería ardua la tarea de actualizar las distintas secciones del código donde se hace uso de rutas.

Además de implementar rutas amigables. He estado investigando y en muchos casos hacen uso del framework laravel u otros. Pero pienso que para el tamaño del proyecto, esto seria demasiados recursos incensarios.

He encontrado un tutorial, en donde dan seguimiento muy parecido a lo que comento

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTJIETc1rmU&t=900s

Sin embargo no logro entender como es que siguiendo estos patrones puedo acceder a las métodos de las clases que se encuentran en los directorios

index.php

```
<?php
require_once("system/core/Routing.php");

$objRouter = new Router();

echo "Ruta actual: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];

echo "<pre>";
print_r($objRouter->getUri());
echo"</pre>";

$controller = $objRouter->getController();
$method = $objRouter->getMethod();
$parameter = $objRouter->getParameter();

echo "Controller: " . $controller . "<br>";
echo "Method: " . $method . "<br>";
echo "Parameter: " . $parameter . "<br>";
```

Routing.php

```
<?php

    class Router{

        public $uri;
        public $controller;
        public $method;
        public $parameter;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->setUri();
            $this->setController();
            $this->setMethod();
            $this->setParameter();
        }

        public function setUri(){
            $this->uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
        }

        public function setController(){
            $this->controller = $this->uri[2] === '' ? 'Home' : $this->uri[2];
        }

        public function setMethod(){
            $this->method = !empty($this->uri[3]) ? $this->uri[3] : "exec";
        }

        public function setParameter(){
            $this->parameter = !empty($this->uri[4]) ?$this->uri[4] : '';
        }

        public function getUri(){
            return $this->uri;
        }

        public function getController(){
            return $this->controller;
        }

        public function getMethod(){
            return $this->method;
        }

        public function getParameter(){
            return $this->parameter;
        }

    }//end class Router
?>
```

.htaccess

```
# Permite reescribir las peticiones de URL
RewriteEngine On

# Si el archivo y la carpeta no existen hacer siguiente reescritura
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Redirecciona todas las peticiones a index
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Por cualquier cosa les muestro la estructura de directorios en donde quisiera implementar el sistema de ruteo.

```
│   autoload.php
│   index.php
│   README.md
│
├───assets
│   └───img
│           create_post.svg
│           loupe.svg
│           send_message.svg
│           user_photo.jpg
│
├───config
│       PATH.php
│
├───controllers
│       .gitkeep
│       ConnectionDB.php
│       UserMapper.php
│       UserService.php
│
├───model
│       .gitkeep
│
│
├───styles
│       index.css
│
└───views
    │   .gitkeep
    │
    ├───components
    │   │   .gitkeep
    │   │   head.php
    │   │   login.php
    │   │   register.php
    │   │
    │   ├───actions
    │   │       RegisterUser.php
    │   │
    │   ├───Header
    │   │       header.css
    │   │       header.php
    │   │
    │   └───PostsScrolling
    │           postsScrolling.css
    │           PostsScrolling.php
    │
    ├───private
    │   │   .gitkeep
    │   │
    │   ├───Chat
    │   │       Chat.php
    │   │
    │   ├───Home
    │   │       Home.php
    │   │
    │   └───Post
    │           Create.php
    │
    └───public
        │   .gitkeep
        │
        └───Login
            │   Login.php
            │
            ├───js
            │       animationStars.js
            │
            └───styles
                    login.css
                    stars.css
```

Salida de index.php

[image: Salida de index.php]

De igual manera escucho recomendaciones para mejorar la estructura de directorios que estoy manejando.
De antemano, gracias.

Comment: No entiendo, preguntas sobre sistema de rutas para construir tus urls o auto carga de clases?

Comment: Actualmente para acceder a algun archivo de las vistas, paso las direcciones dinamicamente por variables de sesion por ejemplo: <a href="<?php echo ($_SESSION['SITE_ROOT'] . "index.php?register");?>">Registrate</a>

Comment: Aunque ahora que lo preguntas, pienso que se debería de implementar un sistema para cada caso. Uno para la autocarga de clases  y otro para el acceso dinámico de los archivos en diferentes partes del código